# How can i download a file with a specific name in angular typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi Following is a small snippet of code in my angular component.

```
this.messageHistoryService.getMessageHistoriesCSV1(msgHistoryRequest).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log(data.messageHistoryBytes);
   let file = new Blob( [data.messageHistoryBytes] , { type: 'plain/text' });   
   let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  }
);
```

the above code works and downloads  file in the browser . How ever i would like to give a specific name to the downloaded file for example download.csv . . how can i achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip is to create a 'temporary' `<a>` tag and simulate a click on it.

Try this:

```
var linkToFile = document.createElement('a');
linkToFile.download = filename;
linkToFile.href = fileURL;
linkToFile.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replace your

```
window.open(fileURL);
```

to:

```
 window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file , "filename");
```

Comment: It works but is not really stable enough for production. As MDN Doc says `Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user.` See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveOrOpenBlob

Answer (score 0):

```
this.messageHistoryService.getMessageHistoriesCSV1(msgHistoryRequest).subscribe(
  (data) => {

    console.log(data.messageHistoryBytes);


   let file = new Blob( [data.messageHistoryBytes] , { type: 'plain/text' });   
   let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

   // window.open(fileURL);

  var linkToFile = document.createElement('a');
  linkToFile.download = "message-history.csv";
  linkToFile.href = fileURL;
  linkToFile.click();

    this.executingElasticSearchQuery = false;

  }

);
```

i rewrite the code like this and it works